# what's the current way to stream a /dev/video to internet by ffmpeg after the ffserver is deprecated?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, streaming, webcam

I'm studying how to live stream my webcam which would be recognized as /dev/video0 in linux to the internet. I'm trying ffmpeg, now get the following method works:

1.create a ffserver.conf file

```
HTTPPort            8090
HTTPBindAddress     0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 200
MaxClients      100
MaxBandWidth    500000
CustomLog       -

<Feed camera.ffm>
File            /tmp/camera.ffm
FileMaxSize     200M
</Feed>

<Stream camera.mjpeg>
Feed camera.ffm
Format mpjpeg
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoIntraOnly
VideoBitRate 4096
VideoBufferSize 4096
VideoSize 640x480
VideoQMin 5
VideoQMax 51
NoAudio
Strict -1
</Stream>
```

2.run the server by command :

```
ffserver -f ffserver.conf
```

3.run the ffmpeg to open the camera

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 15 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/camera.ffm
```

It seems that it works good. However, the official wiki of ffmpeg says the ffserver is deprecated but I'm difficult to find the alternative way to make it work (without ffserver). Do I still need the ffserver.conf file? Or I just need some pure command with ffmpeg?